# Make Radio Button Clickable Link

Tags: html, css

I have a link that holds a radio button, which I want to make a clickable link.  I've tried:

```
<a href="/">
  <input type="radio" style="pointer-events:none;">
</a>
```

This prevents anything from happening when I click the radio button.  I would like it to follow the link. Any ideas?

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: Bind a click handler to the radio button, don't wrap it in a link.

Comment: Instead of making the radio button a clickable link, have you tried doing what needs to be done on the click event of the radio button?

Answer (score 8):

You can use JavaScript to turn elements like that into a link. E.g.:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="window.location='/';" />
```

If other elements should be combined on the link with the radio button, put the `onclick` attribute on the wrapping element.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an `<a>` tag, try surrounding the radio button with a `<div>` with an `onClick` event:

```
<div onClick="window.location = 'http://google.com/';">
    <input type="radio" style="pointer-events:none;"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why bother with the div wrapper at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com'; return false;" />
```