# Click radio buttons that are used as links in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, radio-button

I am working on a website for work and have two options for radio buttons.  I've used `<a>` tags as wrappers for the text and radio button to send the user to a specific webpage of that website.  The radio buttons and text work each perfectly well on Firefox.  On Chrome however, the text works fine as a link.  The radio buttons on the other hand do not work.  The page just refreshes and nothing happens.  I even decided to add a submit so it directs it to one of those pages, with no success as of now.  I tried to replicate the code as close as I could to the code from the website down below.

https://jsfiddle.net/hLph4at4/1/

```
<form name="frmSite" style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;"> 
  <a class="loginPg_choices" href="www.youtube.com">
    <input type="radio" name="site" value="1" id="radio_btn_1" style="float: left; clear: both;" />
    <span style="float: left; margin: -2px 0 0 5px;">Take me to youtube.</span>
    <br/> 
  </a>
  <a class="loginPg_choices" href="www.google.com">
    <input type="radio" name="site" value="1" id="radio_btn_1" style="float: left; clear: both;" />
    <span style="float: left; margin: -2px 0 0 5px;">Take me to google.</span>
    <br/> 
  </a>
  <a href="#" type="submit" value="Submit" title="Login" style="float: right; clear: both;">
    Submit
  </a>
</form>
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568679/make-radio-button-clickable-link

Answer (score 0):

You could add an onclick attribute to your  tag, e.g. `onclick="window.location.href = 'https://youtube.com'"`

Or, as an updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hLph4at4/7/

That will always be called (unless the propagation is stopped), which also includes the radio button.