# Looking to create a survey in HTML where each answer is a button that links you to an equivalent question

Tags: html, button, boolean, survey

I want to create a simple survey as an HTML file, where below each question is a Yes and a No button. (or True and False)

Depending which one you click, you are consecutively taken to a different page containing the next question, but the question is different depending on whether you clicked Yes or No.

I created a simple decision tree to describe a situation where that would be applicable to me:
[decision_tree_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooGsC.png)

I googled this but I couldn't find what I was looking exactly. Thanks :)

edit: Please note, the survey is not supposed to collect or send data. I just want to run it on my computer and reach a branch of the tree, whichever that might be. Nothing further.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and make the buttons a hyperlink and link it to the other question (page).
Here is an example 
[Make Radio Button Clickable Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568679/make-radio-button-clickable-link)

Comment: I see. I just tried this. Basically I've made several HTML documents each containing one question and a yes/no. Those yes/no's link to the next HTML containing the next question and so forth. Do I do it right? Is there any way to unite all those HTML documents into one, or is there no point doing that in the first place? Thanks :)

Comment: There is no point in doing that but it is possible by using Javascript/Jquery.